# how to edit built in twig function - extension

Tags: php, symfony, twig, templating

I'm using twig engine over symfony2 framework and building multi-sites system,
for that I want to customize the extends built in function,
to be a bit more focus what I want is to change the extends function to custom_extends that will add a folder from a server variable, lets say my server variable is "General" I want

```
{% custom_extends 'AcmeBundle:Default:index.html.twig' %} === {% exntends 'AcmeBundle:General/Default:index.html.twig' %}
```

Comment: If you want to modify the behaviour of TWIG and introduce a new tag, check out their guide, but keep in mind it's considered an advanced topic: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#id4

Comment: this link is for adding a tag\filter I want to use the existing one and  add it some more functionality as in the example

Comment: When you make the new custom_extends tag, you can Extend the existing PHP classes TWIG uses to modify their behaviour. You cannot modify the existing tag directly, unless you modify the TWIG library itself (which you shouldn't)

Answer (score 0):

In the end instead of rewriting the render function I've added a filter for the path so

```
{% exntends 'AcmeBundle:Default:index.html.twig'|add_template() %} === {% exntends 'AcmeBundle:General/Default:index.html.twig'
```